# Specific number of decimals depending on size of number

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to show "significant digits" of my data set. I have a dataset with both high and low numbers that I want to present in a data table (by data table here, I mean, a figure in a paper, not a data table (DT) in R). I do not want to settle on a fixed number of decimals. I want numbers >10 = 0 decimals, numbers between 10 to >0 = 1 decimal, 0 to 0.1 = 2 decimals, 0.1 to >0.01 =3 decimals, <0.01 = 4 decimals

I've tried to use functions from a package that does something similar, but that has not worked out for me.
This is what I've tried

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 1)
df <- as_tibble(df)
```

And here's the data

```
df <- structure(list(i.x33.031 = c(13.6221, 0, 104.5006, 28.952, 26.0536, 
4.1116, 62.0904, 136.6475, 0, 292.2651, 6.4563, 94.7135, 34.7291, 
17.8716, 28.9009, 52.2754, 20.5167, 34.3839, 33.5275, 14.7052, 
141.8956, 30.9969, 23.1827, 28.1245, 1.5097, 36.9295, 26.0542, 
29.4029, 152.541, 1.6365), i.x35.034 = c(0.1233, 0, 0.0351, 0.0407, 
0.0497, 0.0153, 0.0856, 0.2297, 0, 0.3863, 0.0032, 0.1962, 0.0873, 
0.0362, 0.0378, 0.1137, 0.0459, 0.0715, 6e-04, 0.0318, 0.3318, 
0.0005, 0.0643, 0.0588, 0.0008, 0.0588, 0.0627, 0.0789, 0.3215, 
0.0215), days_incubated = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: what is your desired output exactly?

Comment: Hi @DPH, I have elaborated a bit on my question

Comment: Can't you just write use some if statements to create the table?

        for number in list:
                   if number == (10^1)
                            number =  number rounded

Comment: Probably, but I'm not quite sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOUR df is

```
> df
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   i.x33.031 i.x35.034 days_incubated
       <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     13.6     0.123               4
 2      0       0                   4
 3    105.      0.0351              4
 4     29.0     0.0407              4
 5     26.1     0.0497              4
 6      4.11    0.0153              4
 7     62.1     0.0856              4
 8    137.      0.230               4
 9      0       0                   4
10    292.      0.386               4
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Use this for rounding only

```
df %>% mutate(i.x33.031 = case_when(i.x33.031 > 10 ~ round(i.x33.031),
                                    i.x33.031 > 0 ~ round(i.x33.031, 1),
                                    i.x33.031 > 0.1 ~ round(i.x33.031, 2),
                                    i.x33.031 > 0.01 ~ round(i.x33.031, 3),
                                    TRUE ~ round(i.x33.031, 4)))
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   i.x33.031 i.x35.034 days_incubated
       <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>
 1      14      0.123               4
 2       0      0                   4
 3     105      0.0351              4
 4      29      0.0407              4
 5      26      0.0497              4
 6       4.1    0.0153              4
 7      62      0.0856              4
 8     137      0.230               4
 9       0      0                   4
10     292      0.386               4
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Rounding both columns

```
result <- df %>% mutate_at(.funs = ~ case_when(. > 10 ~ round(.),
                                    . > 0 ~ round(., 1),
                                    . > 0.1 ~ round(., 2),
                                    . > 0.01 ~ round(., 3),
                                    TRUE ~ round(., 4)), .vars = 1:2)

> print(result)
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   i.x33.031 i.x35.034 days_incubated
       <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>
 1      14         0.1              4
 2       0         0                4
 3     105         0                4
 4      29         0                4
 5      26         0                4
 6       4.1       0                4
 7      62         0.1              4
 8     137         0.2              4
 9       0         0                4
10     292         0.4              4
# ... with 20 more rows
```

**EDIT** for printing as well as rounding

```
df %>% mutate_at(.funs = ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ formatC(0, format = "f", digits = 0),
                                     . < 0.01 ~ formatC(round(., 4), format = "f", digits = 4),
                                     . < 0.1 ~ formatC(round(., 3), format = "f", digits = 3),
                                     . < 1 ~ formatC(round(., 2), format = "f", digits = 2),
                                     . < 10 ~ formatC(round(., 1), format = "f", digits = 1),
                                     . >= 10 ~ formatC(round(., 0), format = "f", digits =0)), .vars = 1:2)

# A tibble: 30 x 3
   i.x33.031 i.x35.034 days_incubated
   <chr>     <chr>              <dbl>
 1 14        0.12                   4
 2 0         0                      4
 3 105       0.035                  4
 4 29        0.041                  4
 5 26        0.050                  4
 6 4.1       0.015                  4
 7 62        0.086                  4
 8 137       0.23                   4
 9 0         0                      4
10 292       0.39                   4
# ... with 20 more rows
```

**NOTE** `Mutate` in the last of your pipe/syntax, i.e. just before printing, is suggested as `formatC` will convert all `double` values to `character`

Comment: Yes, exactly @AnilGoyal, thanks"! I then just need to apply it do many columns, preferably based on their column position.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, however the result I get is that all numbers have 1 decimal. Does ".vars = 1:2) refer to the column numbers that should be rounded?

Comment: .vars means col numbers yes.  Probably you are looking after rounding as well as printing of results.  Try the code, I added in my answer